# mysql query runs slow with multiple conditionals in where

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `A` and `B` both are very large.  I'm trying to do a query like this but it's very slow taking a couple minutes to complete.  The table `A` has an index for `name` and the table `B` has an index for `other_name`.

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.name = 'text' OR B.other_name = 'text'
```

If I do a single conditional each using UNION the query runs very fast as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.name = 'text'

UNION

SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.other_name = 'text'
```

I don't understand why the first runs so much slower than the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second query, the second join is turned to an inner join, because of the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.name = 'text'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.other_name = 'text';
```

This query can make use of an index on `A(name)` and `B(other_name)`, in each of the two parts.

The first query can only use one index.  But, it neither index fully satisfies the query, so it ends up processing the query without an index.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Gordon Linoff's answer, straight from [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html):

> Minimize the OR keywords in your WHERE clauses. If there is no index that helps to locate the values on both sides of the OR, any row could potentially be part of the result set, so all rows must be tested, and that requires a full table scan. If you have one index that helps to optimize one side of an OR query, and a different index that helps to optimize the other side, use a UNION operator to run separate fast queries and merge the results afterward.